# Unable to switch to local branch from master

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm not sure what is going on here, I switched to my master branch to pull down the latest changes, and am now unable to checkout my existing branch.

I am working locally with one origin remote.

When I do git status I see

```
$git status
$=>On Branch Master
$=>Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
$=>nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I do git branch -v I see my branch

```
$git branch -v
$=> master
    my-local-branch
```

But when I checkout the branch, it just says it is up to date with master, and doesn't switch the branch.

```
$git checkout my-local-branch
$=> Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'
```

I have tried checking out other branches, and those work, it is just this one branch. This branch had never been pushed up to the origin remote, could doing git pull from master have overridden it?

Comment: can you run `gitk --all` and take a screenshot?

Comment: Which part of it should I screen shot? The top left corner where the history is doesn't seem to be able to expand far so my branch name and the master branch can't get on the same scrolling screen shot

Comment: Coulf you please post the output of `git status` after `git checkout my-local-branch`?

Answer (score 3):

My bad - my branch name had '#' in it which was causing it to not recognize the checkout command.

The following worked to checkout the branch:

```
git checkout \#<my-branch-name>
```

Comment: Just a little extra info... the `#` sign is the start of a comment in most (all?) unix/linux shells (bash, sh, zsh, etc.), so by saying `git checkout #my-branch-name`, you're really saying `git checkout` and adding a comment (which gets ignored by the shell) saying `my-branch-name`.  As per `git help checkout`, omitting the branch name means "check out the current branch".